# Difference between JsonRpcProvider and API provider

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

What is the difference between JSONRpcProvider and API provider in ethers.js?
Which one should we use?
Which is more benificial and why?

Answer (score 1):

JSON-RPC is a protocol used to communicate with Ethereum nodes over HTTP or IPC. In ethers.js, JSONRpcProvider is a class that implements the JSON-RPC protocol to interact with an Ethereum node. On the other hand, APIProvider is a higher-level abstraction that provides a simplified API to interact with the Ethereum network.

While JSONRpcProvider provides low-level access to the Ethereum network, APIProvider abstracts away some of the complexity and provides a simpler interface to interact with the network. For example, APIProvider allows you to send transactions, estimate gas prices, and query contract state using a simpler, more intuitive API than the raw JSON-RPC calls required by JSONRpcProvider.

In general, if you need more fine-grained control over your interactions with the Ethereum network, you might prefer to use JSONRpcProvider. However, if you are building a dApp or web3 application and need a more convenient and user-friendly interface for interacting with the Ethereum network, APIProvider might be a better choice.

Ultimately, the choice of which provider to use depends on your specific needs and the complexity of your project. If you are unsure which provider to use, you can start with APIProvider and switch to JSONRpcProvider if you need more control over your interactions with the network.